# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError no non-static method with name='getStatusCode' signature='()I' in class Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Really struggling with this error for our unity game. Our game has firebase and GPGS which we suspect is related but not sure where to look for this.

Anybody had similar or can give us some pointers as to where to look or what is happening.
(i can't reproduce on my android devices)

Managed Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='getStatusCode' signature='()I' in class 
Ljava.lang.Object;
com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.getMethodID(Unknown Source)
com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.nativeProxyInvoke(Native Method)
com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.a(Unknown Source)
com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$1.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
$Proxy14.onFailure(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzk.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:4)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
com.google.android.gms.internal.tasks.zzb.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services- 
tasks@@17.1.0:6)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr clazz, System.IntPtr methodID, 
UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.AndroidReflection.GetMethodMember (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String methodName, 
System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String methodName, 
System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID (System.IntPtr javaClass, System.String methodName, 
System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID[ReturnType] (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String 
methodName, System.Object[] args, System.Boolean isStatic) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID[ReturnType] (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String methodName, 
System.Object[] args, System.Boolean isStatic) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._Call[ReturnType] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) (at 
<00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidClient+<>c__DisplayClass49_0.<AddOnFailureListenerWithSignOut>b__0 
(UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject exception) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
System.Action`1[T].Invoke (T obj) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidTaskUtils+TaskOnFailedProxy.onFailure (UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject 
exception) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, 
System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo 
culture) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at 
<00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy.Invoke (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) (at 
<00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.InvokeJavaProxyMethod (UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy proxy, 
System.IntPtr jmethodName, System.IntPtr jargs) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: 
GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidTaskUtils+TaskOnFailedProxy.onFailure(UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy.Invoke (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) (at 
<00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.InvokeJavaProxyMethod (UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy proxy, 
System.IntPtr jmethodName, System.IntPtr jargs) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
```

Comment: This error is caused by a Plugin, cause it's a Java error. Attach your plugin code, and the code where you call this "getStatusCode" method please

Comment: its in a few places

Comment: The plug in is from Google game play service. There are 4 files that have the getStatusCode Method, they are AndroidTokenClient.cs  AndroidNearbyConnectionClient.cs Androidsavegameclient.cs and AndroidClient.cs. I can send over the scripts but don't know how to on here

Comment: Plug in files with GetStatusCode are on the link below   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_3JrmIK9cKGWhxQi_XG6YmSfSXSonivy?usp=sharing    The plug in is Google game play services for unity ver 0.10.09

Comment: I found another reference in a StansAssets Plug in called AN_GamesCallbackSatusCodes                                                                                                         
        /// <returns>String associated with the status code.</returns>
        public static string getStatusCodeString(int statusCode)
        {
            return "Not yet implemented. Contact plugin developer";
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Quar1972 Did you ever figure this out? I am currently having the same issue with GPGS but on only a few devices.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. put your `jar|arr` librarys into `Unity Path:Assets/Plugins/Android/`.
2. Change Unity Configs. `Build Settings`-->`Build System`，select `Internal`.

When I select Gradle, I had the same error you had, and don't know why. I even had a gradle file in the path.